# Find and Replace using RegEx in Google Sheets for dates

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have links which look something like this https://businessofcannabis.com/2021/02/09/cannabis-company-makes-history-as-first-to-list-on-london-stock-exchange/ I want to remove the dates and I think using find and replace using regex is going to be the quickest way how would I remove "2021/02/09/" this part

I have tried a few different regex expressions but I am very new to it so I can't get it all.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this within `Find and replace` and enabling `search using regex exp`:

```
\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/
```

[image]